# Filtering in Kibana based off one parameter in a series of logs linked by another parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dql

All of my logs are saved with a RequestID indicating the specific requests rout through the server.
Only the nginx logs contain a parameter indicating the HTTP request status that was returned to the client (200, 400, 500...).

Is it possible to filter for only the logs that have a requestID that had a certain value in its nginx log for the HTTP status returned?
For example, I would like to filter for all the logs that contain requestIDs where the request ended in a 500 error response returning to the client.

Thanks!